# STM32F407VET6 - How can I handle frame and noise errors in UART?

Tags: stm32, uart, dma

I'm receiving data in UART Rx with DMA and I need to make it immune to disconnections. Now, sometimes I can recover the communication after a disconnection, but I need to recover it always.

Using the debugger I realized that huart1.ErrorCode change its value from 0 to 2,4 or 6. I guess they are noise, frame and noise+frame(?) errors, and after this error the UART stops.

How can I handle this error with my HAL_UART_ErrorCallback and resume UART communication?

Comment: You could disable errors so they don't call the error handler, or you could restart reception in the error handler.

Comment: I would like to restart the reception, but how can I do it? I tried calling HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA but it didn't work.

Comment: You should have some kind of logical protocol able to re-synchronize on top of the raw serial.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: That doesn't help if the error caused the peripheral to become disabled (either due to hardware logic, or in the hardware abstraction library).

Comment: @steevglez: In the worst case you should be able to re-init both DMA and UART and receive again.

Comment: @BenVoigt How can I re-init DMA and UART? I tried HAL_UART_DeInit and HAL_UART_Init but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you really need to use dma?

Comment: @Kartman Yes, because I need to add more UART ports and increase baudrate to 921600

Comment: Yes because you believe you do or yes because you’ve done to calculations? Using dma for tx at least halves the issue. Dma on rx is problematic - sure it can be done, but it can be a painful marriage as you’re experiencing.

Comment: Restart the DMA too

Answer (score 0):

To clarify: we're talking about UART reception only.

I believe this is not something you should do with HAL, rather directly with UART registers. HAL works great for basic and some advanced scenarios, but when you have special needs like this, it becomes a little hard to navigate. A library that controls every single bit of a configuration register would be huge and uncomfortable to use. And this is what we might need. So you will have to add a few lines that work directly with peripheral registers, which are covered in reference manual for the MCU.

There are functions of UART like
a) digital noise filtering
b) noise detection
c) frame error detection - communication broke down half way
d) overrun detection - you receive data while receive data register already has data

which are available in UART control registers and can trigger interrupts and if those throw an error (you will not probably need noise detection, frame error should do it), you need to prevent DMA from moving corrupted received data. Therefore, DMA should be setup with peripheral flow control (UART controls DMA; set it up in stream control register), then it will probably automate this - UART will signal DMA to move received data if and only if the arrived data is OK. If there is a frame error, it will call an interrupt, where you will need to do some housekeeping.

You will need to write a handler for frame error and/or overrun error - it will have to flush the received data register to make sure the next data doesn't cause an overrun error, and you will have to reset all UART flags (at least frame error and overrun error)